# ravel elements in position contiguous order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, tensor

From

```
 np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

I want to get it as a 1D array where contiguous elements, i.e. `[n]` and `[n+1]` were contiguous in the original matrix as well.

For this simple 2x2 matrix one such 1D array would be

```
[1,2,4,3] or [1,3,4,2]
```

, which cannot be attained by neither `np.reshape` nor `np.ravel` (even using the `order` optional argument). Ideally I'd like to this for arbitrary number of array axes.

Just to be clear, in a matrix I consider the elements [i,j] and [p,q] to be contiguous if `|j-q|=1` and `i=p` or the similar statement with i and j and p and q exchanged. For a n-dimensional tensor I consider two elements to be contiguous if all but one index are the same and the index that changed changed by 1 unit.

Do I have to make a function for this or numpy has it already?

Comment: `Do I have to make a function for this or numpy has it already?` - Nope, there's no builtin. Does that answer your question?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html#numpy.nditer seems to have an option for "contiguous operands" but is not clear what it means. I have tried `for x in np.nditer(_a, op_flags=[['readonly','contig']]):
    print(x)` but it just prints them in the regular way